# Django automate Import-Export

Tags: django, django-import-export

I've installed succesfully django import-export to import csv files and CSV files can be imported via the Admin console.
As the same CSV file containing different data needs to be imported on a regular basis, is it possible to automate this via a script or would you recommend a different solution?

Comment: while csv import/export are really good, but if you are working with large data sets I recommend using direct import/export from your database (directly export from mysql or postgresql)

Comment: Thanks Ali, Mordaunt and bmihelac. It's a simple database and still in development phase so your answers should help me further.

Comment: I will switch to Postgresql so it will be possible to enter the CSV file directly into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script or [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/) and then use a cron job to run it automatically.

If you need to send data to your application regularly you should think about creating an API to handle incoming data.

It really depends on context though - could you expand on your problem?

Answer (score 0):

See Import management command for django-import-export

https://gist.github.com/bmihelac/434fceb6ba8e752f08d3

As @mordaunt said, appropriateness of using depends of context.